# Unreal Engine replace default keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, unreal-engine4

I know it seems like a stupid question, but I can't manage to change the default keyboard shortcuts in Unreal Engine (v4.18).

**What I want to do :**

I want to navigate in the game preview (when clicking "play") with the keyboard shortcuts that follows :

- Z to move forward (Actual default W)
- Q to move left (Actual default A)
- S to move backward (Actual default S)
- D to move right (Actual default D)

**How I tried to solve it :**

I went to "Edit->Editor preferences->Keyboard shortcuts" then I searched for "viewport navigation" after reading a post. There, I set up my changes like this :

[image: My actual setup]

I then closed the window, but I still have to use the "defaults" bindings to navigate, and this is actually a pain because I'm not on a QWERTY keyboard.

I restarted the editor many times and also restarted the computer, my changes are visible in the shortcuts configuration, but they seem to not be applied.

Some help would be appreciated because I couldn't find any over the forums or the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to run ue as admin.
2. Check [config files](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Basics/ConfigurationFiles/) in your project folder, you can always create your own config file with your keybindings. (make sure you have permission to write to file.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Project Settings... > Engine > Input > Bindings > Action Mappings / Axis Mappings
[Screenshot for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miXDp.png)
After that, you can change your keyboard shortcuts for the "game preview".
Good luck with your game o/